# Adding Space Between two Rows

Tags: vb.net

I am generating the Table at runtime dynamically ,how can i add the space between the two  rows

Comment: What type of table - WPF, HTML? Do you have some code to share?

Comment: We need more information, thanks

Comment: Voting to close as "not a real question" -- 6 months without clarification

Answer (score 2):

Try the carriage return?

vbCrLf

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Add a row with empty cell values. give it a height.